# How to convert an OpenXml.Spreadsheet to XML whit C#?

Tags: c#, excel, xml, spreadsheet, openxml

**Problem:** I want to populate a spreadsheet with the
*DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet* class (see example code below). Instead of writing the content directly to a file, I'm using a *MemoryStream* to hold the data in memory. After all, data are in the workbook I intend to "serialise" it to a plane XML (see example generated by excel below).

**Question:** How can I convert with C# the workbook in MemoryStream to the same XML format as Excel generated? Is my solution approach correct or is a simpler solution available?

My intention is to use the XML string in combination with a WebAPI (as a GET reply).

**Creating a spreatsheet with OpenXML:**

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;

private void CreateSpreadsheet()
{
    using var mem = new MemoryStream();

    var spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(mem, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);

    // Add a WorkbookPart to the document.
    var workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
    workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();

    // Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart.
    var worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
    worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

    // Add Sheets to the Workbook.
    var sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart!.Workbook.AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());
    
    // Add some content
    var worksheet = new Worksheet();
    var sheetData = new SheetData();
    var row = new Row();
    var cell = new Cell()
    {
        CellReference = "A1",
        DataType = CellValues.String,
        CellValue = new CellValue("Microsoft")
    };
    row.Append(cell);
    sheetData.Append(row);
    worksheet.Append(sheetData);
    worksheetPart.Worksheet = worksheet;

    // Append a new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
    var sheet1 = new Sheet()
        { Id = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart), SheetId = 1, Name = "mySheet1" };
    sheets.Append(sheet1);
    

    workbookPart.Workbook.Save();

    // Close the document.
    spreadsheetDocument.Close();
    
    // --> How to convert the MemoryStream to the desired XML-format?

}
```

**Example XML generated by Excel:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <Author>Autor</Author>
  <LastAuthor>Autor</LastAuthor>
  <Created>2022-03-10T08:37:48Z</Created>
  <LastSaved>2022-03-10T08:40:32Z</LastSaved>
  <Company>Organization</Company>
  <Version>16.00</Version>
 </DocumentProperties>
 <OfficeDocumentSettings xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <AllowPNG/>
 </OfficeDocumentSettings>
 <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
  <WindowHeight>16980</WindowHeight>
  <WindowWidth>-13936</WindowWidth>
  <WindowTopX>0</WindowTopX>
  <WindowTopY>0</WindowTopY>
  <ActiveSheet>1</ActiveSheet>
  <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
  <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
 </ExcelWorkbook>
 <Styles>
  <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
   <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s62">
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="0%"/>
  </Style>
 </Styles>
 <Worksheet ss:Name="DataSet1">
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="6" ss:ExpandedRowCount="5" x:FullColumns="1"
   x:FullRows="1">
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:Index="4"><Data ss:Type="String">VCD3</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">XCD6</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">AFG</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:Index="4"><Data ss:Type="Number">109.78827487289099</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">123.00725769310399</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">115.917908055864</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">ABC1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Formula="=SUM(R2C4:R2C42)-SUM(RC[2]:RC[40])"><Data ss:Type="Number">1.4542479670879516</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="Number">1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">109.555181207937</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">122.74918217899599</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">114.95482926783799</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">CBA2</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Formula="=SUM(R2C4:R2C42)-SUM(RC[2]:RC[40])"><Data ss:Type="Number">8.1808815475339429</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="Number">1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">106.139988953288</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">118.97265998247801</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">115.419910138559</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">DEA3</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Formula="=SUM(R2C4:R2C42)-SUM(RC[2]:RC[40])"><Data ss:Type="Number">3.4102360956978828E-2</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="Number">1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">109.780888636361</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">122.999088939155</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">115.899360685386</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table>
  <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
   <PageSetup>
    <Header x:Margin="0.3"/>
    <Footer x:Margin="0.3"/>
    <PageMargins x:Bottom="0.75" x:Left="0.7" x:Right="0.7" x:Top="0.75"/>
   </PageSetup>
   <Panes>
    <Pane>
     <Number>3</Number>
     <ActiveRow>56</ActiveRow>
     <ActiveCol>6</ActiveCol>
    </Pane>
   </Panes>
   <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
   <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
  </WorksheetOptions>
 </Worksheet>
 <Worksheet ss:Name="DataSet2">
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="6" ss:ExpandedRowCount="5" x:FullColumns="1"
   x:FullRows="1">
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:Index="4"><Data ss:Type="String">VCD3</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">XCD6</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">AFG</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:Index="4"><Data ss:Type="Number">109.78827487289099</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">123.00725769310399</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">115.917908055864</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">ABC1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Formula="=SUM(R2C4:R2C42)-SUM(RC[2]:RC[40])"><Data ss:Type="Number">1.4542479670879516</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="Number">1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">109.555181207937</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">122.74918217899599</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">114.95482926783799</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">CBA2</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Formula="=SUM(R2C4:R2C42)-SUM(RC[2]:RC[40])"><Data ss:Type="Number">8.1808815475339429</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="Number">1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">106.139988953288</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">118.97265998247801</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">115.419910138559</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">DEA3</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Formula="=SUM(R2C4:R2C42)-SUM(RC[2]:RC[40])"><Data ss:Type="Number">3.4102360956978828E-2</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="Number">1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">109.780888636361</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">122.999088939155</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">115.899360685386</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table>
  <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
   <PageSetup>
    <Header x:Margin="0.3"/>
    <Footer x:Margin="0.3"/>
    <PageMargins x:Bottom="0.75" x:Left="0.7" x:Right="0.7" x:Top="0.75"/>
   </PageSetup>
   <Selected/>
   <Panes>
    <Pane>
     <Number>3</Number>
     <ActiveRow>31</ActiveRow>
     <ActiveCol>11</ActiveCol>
    </Pane>
   </Panes>
   <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
   <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
  </WorksheetOptions>
 </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Answer (score 1):

A XLSX file is a zip-archive containing several xml files (just rename an excelfile to .zip and open it to see the structure). So what you could do is opening your MemoryStream with [System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive?view=net-6.0)  and extract the xml files you are interested in. However, since the content is spread across multiple files (for instance there is one file per worksheet) you will have to merge those files into the desired xml output structure yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. It's a good starting point but I hoped to find a more simplified solution. The conversion is available in Excel, is there no way to do it externally?